# jQuery - Need to access PHP array values received after a successful ajax POST operation

Tags: arrays, jquery

**PLATFORM:**

jQuery, PHP, mySQL

**WHAT I HAVE:**

I am using jQuery to process information from a form and send all the POST data to a php file that does several operations and returns an array of data along with other necessary data. One of the arrays is an array of an array. I need to access this array of array values in such a way that I can append each of those nested array values to a table.

**WHAT I NEED:**

I have been battling out with the jquery code to get this to work for a long time but it does not work. So if any one can help me out with the **jquery code**, I would really appreciate that. Thanks in advance.

**TABLE STRUCTURE**

```
fname   lname    city
Ed        Al      SA
Bob       B       MN
Chris     V       KJ
```

**PHP code**

```
//Content of my PHP file that return json encoded data
$success = 1;

$new_rows_data['fname'] = array();
$new_rows_data['lname'] = array();
$new_rows_data['city'] = array();

$result = mysql_query("SELECT fname, lname, city FROM table LIMIT 3");
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) 
{
    $new_rows_data['fname'][] = $row['fname'];
    $new_rows_data['lname'][] = $row['lname'];
    $new_rows_data['city'][]  = $row['city']
}

print json_encode(array('success' => $success, 'new_rows_data' => $new_rows_data));
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
$('#button_delete').click(function() {  

  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',  
   cache: false,
   url: 'test.php',
   data: $('#form1').serialize(), 
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data) {            

      if(data.success == '1')
      {
             jQuery.each(data.new_rows_data, function(i, val) 
            {
                 $('#table').append('<tr>'+

                          '<td>'+val.fname+'</td>'+           
                          '<td>'+val.lname+'</td>'+           
                          '<td>'+val.city+'</td>'+           

                  '</tr>');   

            });
      }//END if
     }       
   }) //END ajax

  return false;
});
```

I am trying to get this new data to get appended to an existing table with id # table, so that i appears like the following **DESIRED OUTPUT**:

```
First Name   Last Name  City
  Orko           C      OI    ---> (Existing row of data)
  Gordon        Flash   KS    ---> (Existing row of data)
  Ed             Al      SA    ---> New row of data that just got appended
  Bob            B       MN    ---> New row of data that just got appended
 Chris           V       KJ    ---> New row of data that just got appended
```

Comment: what does "it doesn't work mean"? Is it receiving the data back from the server? Is it looping through the data properly? There's a lot of places this could go wrong...what are the symptoms?

Comment: Deleted my answer as it was no longer relevant... Have you tried @cballou's suggestion? What exactly isn't working? Is the success function being called? If you add an error handler function does this fire?

Comment: @Brandon @jammus I have tried @cballou's suggestion. The success function is being called. It's the appending to the table part that is not working. The following code does not produce the intended effect of adding the new rows to the end of the table: jQuery.each(data.new_rows_data, function(i, val)  {   $('#table').append('<tr>'+
'<td>'+val.fname+'</td>'+           '<td>'+val.lname+'</td>'+           '<td>'+val.city+'</td>'+            '</tr>');   
  });
Hope I make sense. Thanks.

Comment: @Brandon Yes, it's receiving the response back from the server. It seems to be looping properly in the PHP file and its sending me the other responses correctly such as the data.success value as 1. I have tried adding an error handler and it does not trigger. If I do an alert(data.success); in the success event, it alerts me as: 1, which is correct. I think it is the jQuery.each loop where it stops working/does not work ( I mean it does not add the data contained in 'new_rows_data' to the end of the table. That's the functionality I am losing. Hope this helps. Thank you.

Comment: @Devner Brandon's question still stands, though. What is happening instead of the expected behavior? Are you getting a JavaScript error? Does the row appending code simply have no effect? Have you verified that your $('#table') selector is matching what you think it is? Is the data structure returned in data.new_rows_data what you expect?

Comment: @Jimmy Actually, Nothing happens! I wish I could have told you what exactly it was, had it done something wrong. But because of that so called error/bug, everything is just static. In case I put alert(data.success); just before jQuery.each( ... code, then I get an alert showing me the alert as: 1 --> We obtain this value from the PHP value. Once it reached the jQuery.each( ... code, it simply skips it as if it was never present. No JS errors. Yes, the row appending code simply have no effect! Yes, table selector is correct.

Comment: @Jimmy As far as PHP is concerned, it's sending the correct response. I tested it in a stand-alone PHP script and it is working fine. I am novice in jquery, so I feel that I am not able to access the array elements correctly (or maybe my code is not correct for accessing them). Please note that new_rows_data is an array of arrays and not a single array by itself. So maybe the code to access the child-arrays element is wrong. Does that throw some light on the issue?

Comment: shouldn't be data[0].success? data[0].new_rows_data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append has never been very friendly to me when I start combining text and objects inside it. Try this:

```
$.each(data.new_rows_data, function(i, val) {
   var tr = $('<tr></tr>');

   $.each(val, function(i, newVal){
      var td = $('<td></td>').text(newVal);
      tr.append(td);
   });

   $('#table').append(tr);
});
```

Should get the job done.

**To Change to Multiple Rows with 3 Columns:**

Best to change you're PHP array build to:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT fname, lname, city FROM table LIMIT 3");
$i = 0;
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) 
{
    $new_rows_data[$i]['fname'] = $row['fname'];
    $new_rows_data[$i]['lname'] = $row['lname'];
    $new_rows_data[$i]['city']  = $row['city'];
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Wow! I think we are finally getting somewhere. It currently does append the data to the table but in another way than intended. This is how it works with the code you gave me. Say that the records returned are 5 in number, then instead of creating 5 rows with 3 columns of data in it, it creates 5 COLUMNS with 3 rows of data in it. I think the rows are swapped with the columns and need to be vice versa. I think that change would do it. I tried changing the code, but whatever I do, it breaks it. So I thought if maybe you knew of a quick way to fix this. Thanks much.

Comment: I think it'd be easier to change the way PHP builds the array. Refer to the updated answer. :)

Comment: AWESOME! This would be the answer of the day! Your trick worked! Thank you so much! It's appending all the retrieved columns. Just wondering if I had to add a static column with a checkbox in it and populate it with the record id so that I can select the row/record and delete it, where should I modify it in the jquery code?

Comment: Couple options. What I recommend is adding whatever you wanted inside the column into your `$new_rows_data[$i]['something_new']` array and in the jquery where it says `text()` change to `html()`. The other, if it's totally static, to do something like `$('<td></td>').html('<input type="checkbox" />').appendTo(tr)` either before or after the loop.

Comment: +1 Once again, AWESOME! I implemented it and it works! Appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this from a search and want to point out, where your code has:

```
$new_rows_data['fname'][] = $row['fname'];
$new_rows_data['lname'][] = $row['lname'];
$new_rows_data['city'][]  = $row['city'];
```

What's happening here is that you're building several parallel arrays.  In javascript individual values would be visible as e.g. `data.new_rows_data.fname[0]` for the fname of the first row.  When you do `$.each(...)` on this, your function should see arguments of i=="fname" and val equal to a 3-element array of first names.

munch's answer accomplishes the same thing with an explicit index, but for your specific case I would code like this:

```
$new_rows_data[] = $row;
```

Or for cases when the calculation of values is not so straightforward:

```
$new_rows_data[] = array(
    'foo' => get_foo($row),
    'bar' => $row['bar']
);
```

In either case, new_rows_data then becomes an array of objects with properties matching your PHP array keys, which would be accessible in javascript as `data.new_rows_data[1].fname`.  Your `$.each(...)` loop would now see i as an integer, and val as an object with the properties you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue I see is one of loose typing:

```
if(data.success === 1)
```

should be

```
if(data.success == '1')
```

because as far as javascript is concerned, all returned data from AJAX is a string.  I just noticed from @Jammus that your PHP code should also switch your `$success` variable to have either a value of `0` or `1`.